# Magento 2 Custom API: Need to create an API which gets the data from a table in database

Tags: magento2, database, rest-api, banner-slider

I have a magento store for which I was using the **Magestore Bannerslider** module to show a simple carousel on the homepage.

But now I am experimenting with a headless approach, and there's no API to get the banner details from the database.

Any ideas how will I create a custom API module to query the table of this module

> magestore_bannerslider_banner

Thanks!

Comment: which version of magento are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the data from the database using rest? Are you using it internally (in the same code/site/environment)? Or you want to get the banners to somewhere externally?

If it is the second case, then you have to ask the developers to implement that.

If it is the first case, then you should just get the collection.

If you want to implement your own API that gets data from that table... well... it's not as easy.
You have to create a service contract for that.